# in javascript how to require multiple form fields when one is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

In an html5 page I have 2 fields in a standard form. What I need is when users select on either one of these fields to require data in the other field. Any blank field on submission requires all related fields to contain data.

This is working okay for the first field when the second field is not filled by the user.  But when the second field is filled and the first field is blank it is not working - its bypassing this condition and going to the checkSubmission function.

i.e.

```
     <script language="javascript">

         function validateAndSend() {
        if (myform.field1.value != '' && myform.field2.value == '') {
            alert('You have to enter data in field2.');
            return false;
       } else if (myform.field2.value != '' && myform.field1.value == '') {
          alert('You have to enter data in field 1.');
          return false;
      } else {
       checkSubmission();
         }
     }

       function checkSubmission(){
       var r = confirm('Are you sure you are ready to submit?');
       if (r == true) {
        myform.submit();
        }else{
         return false;
       }
      }
    </script>

   The HTML -
    <form name="myform" action="mypage.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="validateAndSend();return false;">
      <select name="field1" id="textarea1">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="data1">data1 select</option>
    <option value="data2">data 2 select</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="field2">
```

I also have up to 4 multiple fields that should all again should relate to one another when users select one of them; they all have to be required once one of the 4 are selected in the form.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For you case, I think it would be better if you can provide us the fiddle, e.g. JSfiddle.

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/qfw77hez/).

Comment: Have you tried using `required` attribute at `html` of form elements?

Comment: Maybe you think about this. https://jsfiddle.net/qfw77hez/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put `required` on your input fields?

```
<input name="whatever" required>
```

That takes care of everything without javascript

Comment: That doesn't work for the OP's requirement, which is "when users select on either one of these fields to require data in the other field" - in which case if both fields are blank it should pass validation.

Comment: Ahh I see. Then maybe he can just add the required attribute with jquery once one of the fields is selected